# Issue with Django --> Apache WSGI deployment

Tags: python, django, apache, wsgi

I have a django app running in VS Code 1.86.2 on a Debian 12 machine using Python 3.11.2.  I'm working on a test deployment to Apache 2.4.57 and mod_wsgi 4.9.4.  I've been working through docs from Apache and Django.

At this point I am able to load html documents from the deployed site, but the Django template tags are not being processed.  For example I see the below text in the browser.

```
    {% extends "base.html" %} {% block title %}my app{% endblock %} {% block content %} {% csrf_token %}
    Record Lookup
    Search Key:
    {% endblock %}
```

```
Excerpt from apache2.conf: 
Listen 9876 <VirtualHost *:9876> 
DocumentRoot "/var/www/proj1_1/app_1/templates" 
ServerName www.trsws3.com </VirtualHost> 
WSGIScriptAlias /test_site/ /var/www/app1/app1/wsgi.py 
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/proj_1/app1 
<Directory /var/www/proj_1/app1> 
<Files wsgi.py> Require all granted </Files> </Directory>
```

I'm new to the Django and Apache world so hoping for some guidance on where to start diagnosing this issue.

Comment: Show your server config. It looks like you are accessing html outside django. You should only allow django urls to be served.

Comment: Excerpt from apache2.conf:

Listen 9876
<VirtualHost *:9876>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/proj1_1/app_1/templates"
  ServerName www.trsws3.com
</VirtualHost>
WSGIScriptAlias /test_site/ /var/www/app1/app1/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/proj_1/app1

<Directory /var/www/proj_1/app1>
 <Files wsgi.py>
  Require all granted
 </Files>
</Directory>

Comment: Django is not like apache servers. Django doesn't host templates from template folders directly. Meaning, users don't access html templates from templates folders. Django only return html through django views. You must redirect incoming requests to django.

Comment: apache2.conf is mis configured. That's the problem.

Comment: Thank you Pycm - I was able to correct the apache2.conf and the site is working now.

Comment:  Happy it helped somehow.